# How to ignore a list mapping when the list is empty but not null?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, conditional-statements

How to ignore a list mapping when the list is empty but not null.

if source.Divisions (which is an IEnumerable) is null or empty then the des.Divisions shouldn't be mapped:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Event, DataContracts.Event>()
   .ForMember(des => des.Divisions, e => e.MapFrom(source => source.Divisions))
```

I've found the below solution:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Event, DataContracts.Event>()
       .ForMember(des => des.Divisions, e => { 
e.Condition(source => !source.Divisions.IsNullOrEmpty()));
e.MapFrom(source => source.Divisions));
});
```

Is there anyway to simplify the above further?

e.g by creating an extension method.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Event, DataContracts.Event>()
           .ForMember(des => des.Divisions, e => e.MapListIfNotEmpty(source => source.Divisions));
```

Comment: No directly linked to the condition but you don't need to mention the MapFrom portion since both the source and destination collections have the same name. `.ForMember(des => des.Divisions, e => e.Condition(source => !source.Divisions.IsNullOrEmpty()))`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this extension, hope it helps!

```
 public static void MapListIfNotEmpty<TSource, TMapFrom>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource> map,
        Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TMapFrom>> mapFrom)
    {
        map.Condition(src => !mapFrom(src).IsNullOrEmpty());

        map.MapFrom(mapFrom);
    }
```

and you can use it like this:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Event, DataContracts.Event>()
                .ForMember(des => des.Divisions, e => e.MapListIfNotEmpty(source => source.Geographies));
```